# Django - Column repair_repair.startDatetime_repair does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

Al listar incidencias me devuelve el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece ser que al insertar datos en la tabla reparaciones, no se ha insertado startDateTime, y después para listarlo sea necesario. Trato de entrar mediante admin a borrar las reparaciones que les falte ese dato, pero no me deja tampoco listar reparaciones en el admin. ¿Cómo se puede borrar reparaciones insertadas? Utilizo PostgreSql en UbuntuServer.

Modelo

```
class Repair(models.Model):
    startDatetime_repair = models.DateTimeField ('Fecha comienzo reparación',null=True, blank=True)
    endDatetime_repair = models.DateTimeField ('Fecha finalización reparación',null=True, blank=True)
    incidence_repair = models.ForeignKey(Incidence, related_name="incidencia_repair",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    affectedDevice_repair = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name="affectedDevice_repair",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    typeFailure_repair = models.ForeignKey(TypeFailure, related_name="typeFailure_repair",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    typeRepair_repair = models.ForeignKey(TypeRepair, related_name="typeRepair_repair",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    removedDevice_repair = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name="removedDevice_repair",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    placedDevice_repair = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name="placedDevice_repair",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    removedConsumable_repair = models.ForeignKey(Consumable, related_name="removedConsumable_repair",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    placedConsumable_repair = models.ForeignKey(Consumable, related_name="placedConsumable_repair",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    statusAfterRepair_repair = models.ForeignKey(StatusAfterRepair, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    summary_repair = models.TextField('Resumen',null=True, blank=True)
    detail_repair = models.TextField('Detalles',null=True, blank=True)

    class meta:
        verbose_name = 'Reparación'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Reparaciones'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.summary_repair
```

Comment: ¿
has creado el fichero de migraciones y lo has ejecutado?

Comment: Así es. makemigrations y después migrate. ¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: necesitaríamos ver la traza del error completo. En texto, a poder ser